# Severity level in BOOST_LOG_SEV

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, metaprogramming

Why this code line works fine :

```
BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg,debug) << "tst message";
```

while this one fails at compilation time:

```
BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg,trivial::severity_level::debug) << "tst message";
```

Failure message:

```
Error   20  error C2653: 'trivial' : is not a class or namespace name
```

I suppose both - `debug` and `trivial::severity_level::debug` are the same. If I press F12 in my Visual Studio on `debug` it goes exact to `trivial::severity_level::debug` in `trivial.hpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have using namespace `boost::log::trivial`.
In the second case you should specify
`boost::log::trivial::debug`, that is full path to `debug`.

Note, that for standard C++03 code you shouln't write `severity_level`, since it's enum, but since C++11 you can use `boost::log::trivial::severity_level::debug`, if you want.

Comment: but 'BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg,boost::log::trivial::severity_level::debug)' works fine now. Why I should skip 'severity_level' ?